# NURBS trimming, blend surfaces

Tags: nurbs-surface

I'm exploring Blender's NURBS functionality. So far, I've been able to define two curves and create a NURBS surface between them.

Does Blender support more advanced NURBS features like [trimming](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-6DC30BD4-6592-42D9-8FC6-C25D539F29A9) and [blend surfaces](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=GUID-42B4367F-3C10-454A-8C15-05AF450A3107)?

It's fine if the interface is still lacking. If the functionality is available at all, I'll probably want to use it.

FWIW, I'm interested in NURBS because I do a lot of mechanical modeling. Meshes work for that, but NURBS are a much cleaner way to model a lot of man-made objects.

Comment: There was a project to add such functionality just recently, as part of the gsoc. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Jjoonathan/NURBS_Final_Report

Comment: So in other words, trims and blends are not included in the most recent release, correct? If you turn that into an answer to this question, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the results of this GSOC 2014 were included in the master (for a simple user) ? Is it now part of the current Blender (2.74) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality was recently being worked on as part of GSOC 2014. You can view the results of the project [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Jjoonathan/NURBS_Final_Report).

It has not yet been merged into master, but you can compile it yourself (the branch can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/soc-2014-nurbs/)).